# How to keep Dialog open

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

```
private void openDialog(){

    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(TrueAct.this);
    View subView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.newdialog, null);
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage("Enter New");
    builder.setView(subView);

    blEntryExistToday = true;
    builder.setPositiveButton("ADD", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            if (!blEntryExistToday) {
                //CLOSE DIALOG
            }
            else {
                tvM.setText("An entry for this day already exist!");
                //DO NOT CLOSE DIALOG
            }
        }
    });

    builder.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Cancel", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //CLOSE THE DIALOG
        }
    });

    builder.show();
}
```

No matter whether I click ADD or CANCEL, the dialog closes. How can I keep it open if `blEntryExistToday` is `true`.

[image]

I would like to keep the same theme as it is right now, with the color and text.

Comment: By default Dialog calls the dismiss method on button click, you must create  a custom class and extend it as Dialog or AlertDialog and override your own code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can stop setting listener while building **AlertDialog** and set listeners *null* for positive and negative buttons and handle clicks by yourself.

You can change your code this way:

```
private void openDialog() {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(TrueAct.this);
    View subView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.newdialog, null);
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage("Enter New");
    builder.setView(subView);

    blEntryExistToday = true;
    builder.setPositiveButton("ADD", null);
    builder.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", null);

    final AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();

    alertDialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
        @Override
        public void onShow(final DialogInterface dialog) {
            Button positiveButton = alertDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
            positiveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (!blEntryExistToday) {
                        //CLOSE DIALOG
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    } else {
                        tvM.setText("An entry for this day already exist!");
                        //DO NOT CLOSE DIALOG
                    }
                }
            });

            Button negativeButton = alertDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE);
            negativeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Cancel", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    //CLOSE THE DIALOG
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
        }
    });

    alertDialog.show();
}
```

Comment: Thank you... Did the job :)

Answer (score 2):

Don't call `builder.setPositiveButton(..)` or `builder.setNegativeButton(..)`. Instead, add buttons to `R.layout.newdialog` and handle clicks on those buttons. Call `dialog.dismiss()` when you want the dialog to close.

To achieve the same look as the builtin buttons, simply use `style="?android:borderlessButtonStyle"` and `android:textColor="?android:colorAccent"`.

Comment: I like the UI of the default material dialog shows up... I updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

that´s a usual behaviour of `AlertDialog`. In a simple way, you can´t avoid. But You got some possible workarounds:

since API8, you can set an `onShowListener()` (after you call `builder.create()` ):

```
    builder.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener(){

           @Override
        onShow(DialogInterface interface){

        Button positiveButton = builder.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
          positiveButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()){

                @Override
                public void OnClick(View view){

             if (!blEntryExistToday) {
            //CLOSE DIALOG
            builder.dismiss();

                 } else {

            tvM.setText("An entry for this day already exist!");
            //DO NOT CLOSE DIALOG
             // if you doesn´t call builder.dismiss(); it won´t close
                   }                     
                  }
                });    
              }
            });
```

or, a similar way, call the `builder.getButton()` method after you called `builder.show()` without the `onShowListener()` .

Comment: Is there an advantage/disadvantage of choose either or?

Comment: no, both are good enough. I prefere outside without the show listener....but that´s just a lazy-style-decision.. :)

Comment: otherwise, I think it´s more secure to chose the listener solution, because you call the method definetely if the dialog is ready. Maybe, because of some short time delay for any reason, the dialog will not be ready if you call it without the listener....just an assumption.

Answer (score 1):

My situation was a little different. It would be better not requiring add custom buttons and keeping usage of `setPositiveButton`. So:

```
// A function to create the dialog
public static void inputText( Context context, String title, String hint, String posBtn, String negBtn, DialogInterface.OnClickListener listener )
{
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    builder.setTitle( title );

    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) View.inflate( context, R.layout.dialog_input_text, null );
    final EditText input = (EditText) layout.findViewById( R.id.input );
    input.setHint( hint );
    builder.setView( layout );

    builder.setPositiveButton( posBtn, listener );
    builder.setNegativeButton( negBtn, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick( DialogInterface dialog, int which )
        {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    } );

    final Dialog dialog = builder.show();
}
```

And in all usages of this dialog I call the function above like this:

```
DialogInterface.OnClickListener listener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick( DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i )
    {
        final AlertDialog dialog = (AlertDialog) dialogInterface;

        EditText field = (EditText) dialog.findViewById( R.id.input );
        String name = field.getText().toString();

        if( name.equals( "" ) )
        {
            Toast.makeText( MainActivity.this, "Fill with a name.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
            Dialogs.inputText( MainActivity.this, "Rename", longClickFileObject.name, "Ok", "Cancel", this );
        }
        else
        {
            // Do stuff
        }
    }
};

inputText( this, "Rename", longClickFileObject.name, "Ok", "Cancel", listener );
```

It's not using custom buttons and it's still easy read but it has to recreate the dialog and it blinks it.